# How does HTTP frontend server communicate to Websphere

Tags: java, http, web-applications, websphere, port

How does HTTP frontend server (remote) communicate to Websphere?

I have read that WAS plugin installed in the HTTP frontend server will route the requests to Websphere based on plugin-cfg.xml settings.

1. Will the routing be on HTTP protocol or some other binary protocol?
2. What are the implications on Firewall settings in this case? What ports should be kept open on the application server machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the routing be on HTTP protocol or some other binary protocol?

Plugin uses HTTP / HTTPS protocol to communicate with WebSphere. HTTPS is used, if request comes via https and plugin is configured to communicate using htts with WebSphere (has root WebSphere cert added to trusted signers).

> What are the implications on Firewall settings in this case?
>   What ports should be kept open on the application server machine?

After you'll generate `plugin-cfg.xml`, you will see for each of servers, that plugin needs to communicate following fragment:

```
<Server CloneID="s111111" LoadBalanceWeight="1" ConnectTimeout="0" ExtendedHandshake="false" MaxConnections="-1" Name="custTestNode_server1" ServerIOTimeout="0" WaitForContinue="false">
     <Transport Hostname="server1" Port="9080" Protocol="http"/>
     <Transport Hostname="server1" Port="9443" Protocol="https">
        <Property Name="keyring" Value="/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb"/>
        <Property Name="stashfile" Value="/config/webserver1/plugin-key.sth"/>
     </Transport>
  </Server>
```

There are ports, in this case `9080` and `9443`, which will be used to communicate with that server, and that needs to be opened in firewall.

Comment: Gas, Excellent answer. I have a comment though. The communication between Web Server and App Server can be HTTPS even though HTTP is the protocol between browser and the web server. It all depends on the configuration. Also with the newer versions of the App Server, the intelligent management plugin you will have to open additional ports for the management functions besides the ones that connect to the Web Container of the application server(9080 and 9443 in your response)

Comment: @Manglu Yes, good points, thanks. Do you have reference at hand about ports used by the intelligent management? I could update the post. I keep forgetting about that since its relatively new feature. And you can upvote it of course if you like it;)